# Math symbol to represent an operator to convert from double-precision to 32-bit integer value?

Tags: integers

I'm looking for a good mathematical symbol to represent the conversion from a double-precision floating value to an unsigned 32-bit integer value. Does anyone have suggestions for a good Greek letter or a math symbol to express this?

The best candidate I can think of is to use a symbol for a floor function with a subscript like below:

[image]

Is there a more official way to represent this?

Comment: How will you handle negatives ?

Comment: There is not enough context for a relevant answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no common/standard symbology to represent finite types. Neither floating-point nor unsigned integer. And even less for conversions, taking into account that they are not always possible. You can represent the naturals as the set $\mathbb N$, but there is nothing for the floating-point numbers, a special subset of the rationals.

If you want to stress the data type conversion aspect, better use a typecast-like notation. If you just want to express the numerical value, $\text{floor}$ ($\lfloor x\rfloor$) is good enough.